# SQL code not pulling highest date before defined date: Revised

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've decided to edit this for clarity.

Below is my data with the tables.

BLDGID, LEASID, STARTDT, and BRK are in table BRKP

OCCPSTAT and SUITID are in another table called STATUS

INCATT is in another table called BILL

```
BLDGID  LEASID  STARTDT BRK OCCPSTAT SUITID INCCAT
  9999  100 8/5/2011    100000  C   AZ847   AVD
  9999  100 8/5/2013    200000  C   AZ847   AVD
  9999  100 8/5/2015    300000  C   AZ847   AVD
  9999  100 8/5/2017    400000  C   AZ847   AVD
  9999  250 12/1/2012   200000  C   BK497   TIL
  9999  250 12/1/2016   400000  C   BK497   TIL
  9999  250 12/7/2020   500000  C   BK497   TIL
  9999  250 1/31/2023   600000  C   BK497   TIL
  7000  987 2/19/2016       0   C   JT127   MTU
  7000  987 5/19/2020   10000   C   JT127   MTU
  7000  987 3/18/2021   20000   C   JT127   MTU
  7000  987 9/4/2023    30000   C   JT127   MTU
```

What I want is to pull ONE row for each suite ID (there are about 100 unique SUITID's per BLDGID).

In that row, I need the STARTDT to be the highest value BEFORE the date I define.

If I define 20220831 (08/31/2022) it should pull a single row in this case, that would be row 2.

If I define 20160831 (8/31/2016) it should pull only row 1.

I cannot figure out how to get it to pull just 1 row. I can get many.

I've been trying STARTDT=(max(STARTDT)<'20160831') and other variations.

The issue I'm having with no date entered, it would pull 7/5/2022 but, when I enter my date, it pulls nothing.

EDIT Again: I've tried adding the below but, it does not change the number of records returned.

ORDER BY SUITID, STARTDT DESC

SELECT TOP 1 * FROM SUITID, STARTDT

EDIT FURTHER: Example are first first 4 lines of the table. Expanded to show I'm working with a bigger table.

Comment: 1. Please add the whole query you're using. 2. Don't use unnecessary parentheses, this only complicates things.

Comment: working on the parentheses right now. I updated the query for the moment with what is in the system.

Comment: I got you covered with the parantheses, whitespace, and all that with the query. It looks much less scary cleaned up.

Comment: `AND SQLDATA.dbo.CMLEDG.LEASID = BRKP2.LEASID SQLDATA.DBO.BRKP.STARTDT = ...` is invalid. Probably too much cleanup. I guess an `AND` is missing there.

Comment: Have you tried use of **ROW_NUMBER() OVER()** yet? As you have simplified the question it seems even more likely that this is the appropriate technique. By the way what is the "add in" you mention below?

Comment: I'm trying to find a tutorial on how to write the ROW_Number() OVER() could you give me an example? I've learned what I've learned in two weeks. 

It's called Spreadsheet Server from Global Software Inc.

Comment: It also uses SQL Server, is the function you gave available in that one? I can only find examples in Oracle?

Comment: What I tried to add to the code was:

ORDER BY SUITID, STARTDT DESC

SELECT TOP 1 * FROM SUITID, STARTDT

but, in the above example from the question, it doesn't change my results.

Comment: **row_number() over()** is available in SQL Server (we take note of the tags you use to decide how to answer)

Comment: here is an example of how to use it NOTE the column BRK is NOT in the partition by: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/529004/example-use-of-row-number?opt.textResults=true

Comment: This is my fault for being vague in the first place. Imagine the table above with about 5000 more rows and that is what I'm working with. Wouldn't that query only return the single row defined? Or could it be used for a much bigger data set and only pull the bottom row of the individual SUITID? I see how it would solve the tiny table but, I'm confused on how I would scale it to pull 1 row for each suit ID or is the row based off from the SUITID column and not just the bottom record?

Comment: THIS, I made the table you made long and it works. I just need to figure out how to fit it into my query.

Comment: As you have learned it will produce one row FOR EACH UNIQUE COMBINATION of the **partition by** columns. SQL isn't hard, it just takes some time, like any language. Imagine how many years it took for you to master English :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Often* when someone wants data related to a "maximum date" the best technique is to use ROW_NUMBER() OVER()

I think this may produce what you are seeking:

```
SELECT
        BLDGID
      , LEASID
      , STARTDT
      , BRKPNT1
      , OCCPSTAT
      , SUITID
      , INCCAT
FROM (
        SELECT
                br.BLDGID
              , br.LEASID
              , br.STARTDT
              , br.BRKPNT1
              , le.OCCPSTAT
              , le.SUITID
              , rb.INCCAT
              , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY br.BLDGID, br.LEASID, le.OCCPSTAT, le.SUITID, rb.INCCAT
                                  ORDER BY br.STARTDT DESC) AS rowno
        FROM SQLDATA.dbo.CMLEDG cm
        INNER JOIN SQLDATA.dbo.LEAS le   ON cm.BLDGID = le.BLDGID AND cm.LEASID = le.LEASID
        INNER JOIN SQLDATA.dbo.RTBILL rb ON cm.BLDGID = rb.BLDGID AND cm.LEASID = rb.LEASID
        INNER JOIN SQLDATA.dbo.BRKP br   ON cm.BLDGID = br.BLDGID AND cm.LEASID = br.LEASID
        WHERE br.STARTDT < '20160831'
        AND le.OCCPSTAT = 'c'
     ) AS d
 WHERE rowno = 1
```

Inside the OVER() the columns listed for the "partition by" acts a little like your "group by" in that it **re-starts counting at one** when that combination of values changes. So, because this is also uses a descending "order by" of the wanted date you get a value of 1 for the "latest date". When also combined with the where clause you get: *the most recent date before '20160831'*

There are several additional notes I would like to make:

1. The query provided in the question has syntax errors, an AND is missing in this "= BRKP2.LEASID **AND** SQLDATA.DBO.BRKP.STARTDT"
2. I don't follow this: "HAVING SQLDATA.dbo.BRKP.BLDGID **&** SPARM03
3. When providing columns with an alias don't use single quotes, either use [] or "" (i.e. I suggest you reserve use of single quotes only for literals). But, also, there is no need to provide a column alias in this query because you don't actually change the column names anyway.
4. Using tables aliases helps make queries easier to read
5. there is no apparent reason for using GROUP BY because there are no aggregate functions being used
6. a HAVING clause is used to filter for aggregated values that exist only after a group by, There are no aggregated values in this query so there should be no having clause. (A having clause in not a substitute for a where clause.)
7. There is no reason I could find for joining SQLDATA.dbo.BRKP twice

Comment: 1. I'm aware of the missing one, it didn't alter my results so I left it. When I run it, I show no syntex errors and this likely has to do with it being written in sql (ish) code but, is actually being read by an add in to excel called spreadsheet server. I get errors without the many parenthesis.

2. &SPARM03 is unique to the addin I'm using. 

3. I will review how this acts. 

4. The tables are aliased in the add in, I'm not sure how it would look without them, as the addin generates the aliases. It may do it within the program and outside of the query.

Comment: 5. I agaree it is auto generated by the program. 
6. It sounds like I need a where clause. 
7. I agree. 

I'm going to edit my questions and break it down to the drop dead basics with no code.

Comment: Is there a way to mark this as best answer? A little bit of playing with the program and this works PERFECTLY. 

THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of filtering by date on the `HAVING` clause, try filtering using the `WHERE` clause before the `GROUP BY`, like this:

```
        ...

        WHERE ((SQLDATA.dbo.BRKP.STARTDT) < '20160831')
        GROUP BY SQLDATA.dbo.BRKP.BLDGID,
            SQLDATA.dbo.BRKP.LEASID,
            SQLDATA.dbo.BRKP.STARTDT,
            SQLDATA.dbo.BRKP.BRKPNT1,
            SQLDATA.dbo.LEAS.OCCPSTAT,
            SQLDATA.dbo.LEAS.SUITID,
            SQLDATA.dbo.RTBILL.INCCAT
        HAVING (
                ((SQLDATA.dbo.BRKP.BLDGID) & SPARM03)
                AND ((SQLDATA.dbo.LEAS.OCCPSTAT) = 'c')
                )
```

Basically, before grouping, you are pre-filtering the data with only what interests you.

Comment: Tried this, got the exact same results as I've been getting.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you'll need to use a date instead of a string to do the inequality in your HAVING clause:

```
SELECT SQLDATA.dbo.BRKP.BLDGID AS 'BLDGID',
    SQLDATA.dbo.BRKP.LEASID AS 'LEASID',
    SQLDATA.dbo.BRKP.STARTDT AS 'STARTDT',
    SQLDATA.dbo.BRKP.BRKPNT1 AS 'BRKPNT1',
    SQLDATA.dbo.LEAS.OCCPSTAT AS 'OCCPSTAT',
    SQLDATA.dbo.LEAS.SUITID AS 'SUITID',
    SQLDATA.dbo.RTBILL.INCCAT AS 'INCCAT'
FROM SQLDATA.dbo.CMLEDG
INNER JOIN SQLDATA.dbo.LEAS ON SQLDATA.dbo.CMLEDG.BLDGID = SQLDATA.dbo.LEAS.BLDGID
    AND SQLDATA.dbo.CMLEDG.LEASID = SQLDATA.dbo.LEAS.LEASID
INNER JOIN SQLDATA.dbo.RTBILL ON SQLDATA.dbo.CMLEDG.BLDGID = SQLDATA.dbo.RTBILL.BLDGID
    AND SQLDATA.dbo.CMLEDG.LEASID = SQLDATA.dbo.RTBILL.LEASID
INNER JOIN SQLDATA.dbo.BRKP ON SQLDATA.dbo.CMLEDG.BLDGID = SQLDATA.dbo.BRKP.BLDGID
    AND SQLDATA.dbo.CMLEDG.LEASID = SQLDATA.dbo.BRKP.LEASID
INNER JOIN SQLDATA.dbo.BRKP BRKP2 ON SQLDATA.dbo.CMLEDG.BLDGID = BRKP2.BLDGID
    AND SQLDATA.dbo.CMLEDG.LEASID = BRKP2.LEASID SQLDATA.DBO.BRKP.STARTDT = 
        (
            SELECT MAX(SQLDATA.DBO.BRKP.STARTDT)
            FROM SQLDATA.DBO.BRKP
            WHERE SQLDATA.DBO.LEAS.BLDGID = SQLDATA.DBO.BRKP.BLDGID
                AND SQLDATA.DBO.LEAS.LEASID = SQLDATA.DBO.BRKP.LEASID
        )
GROUP BY SQLDATA.dbo.BRKP.BLDGID,
    SQLDATA.dbo.BRKP.LEASID,
    SQLDATA.dbo.BRKP.STARTDT,
    SQLDATA.dbo.BRKP.BRKPNT1,
    SQLDATA.dbo.LEAS.OCCPSTAT,
    SQLDATA.dbo.LEAS.SUITID,
    SQLDATA.dbo.RTBILL.INCCAT
HAVING SQLDATA.dbo.BRKP.BLDGID & SPARM03
    AND SQLDATA.dbo.BRKP.STARTDT < Convert(datetime, '2016-08-31' )
    AND SQLDATA.dbo.LEAS.OCCPSTAT = 'c'
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear *exactly* what you need.  But, clearly you need a `where` clause and to simplify the `GROUP BY`.  So, your query needs something like:

```
SELECT . . .,
       MAX(SQLDATA.dbo.BRKP.STARTDT)
FROM . . .
WHERE SQLDATA.dbo.BRKP.STARTDT < '20160831'
GROUP BY SQLDATA.dbo.BRKP.BLDGID,
    SQLDATA.dbo.BRKP.LEASID,
    SQLDATA.dbo.BRKP.BRKPNT1,
    SQLDATA.dbo.LEAS.OCCPSTAT,
    SQLDATA.dbo.LEAS.SUITID,
    SQLDATA.dbo.RTBILL.INCCAT
HAVING ( (SQLDATA.dbo.BRKP.STARTDT) < '20160831') AND 
         ((SQLDATA.dbo.LEAS.OCCPSTAT) = 'c')
        )
```

It is unclear if any of the other conditions should move the `WHERE` clause as well, but I would guess "yes".

Comment: I guess I can't explain it much better. I'm about 2 weeks into learning SQL. I need the highest record before 8/31/2016. In the table example, I would need it to return the row that contains the date from 2011. 

What the query is doing now is pulling the max date and then excluding it if it's over the date I defined. IE if I run without 8/31/2016 it will return me the row from 2022 but, when I add 8/31/2016 it returns no rows from the example as it is only looking at the max and not pulling the highest record that meets the date.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me for not going through and hooking this all up to your code, but what I am understanding you are looking for is

```
SELECT TOP (1)
```

and then

```
WHERE myDate <= @theDateValue
```

and very importantly

```
ORDER BY myDate DESC
```

This, in very general terms, is the means by which you can get the last record before something.  The performance in the above example would be greatly impacted by whether or not there is an index on 'myDate' because if so, the engine could go directly to the correct page with a few reads and pull the single record you need.

Comment: For whatever reason when I add this to my query, it does sort by DESC but, it didn't do anything to my results. I'm using a program called spreadsheet server and I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it. Also see updated table and multiply it down by about 1000. I'm trying to get 1 row per SUITID returned to me based on the STARTDT (I want the first STARTDT that occur before the date I define).

Comment: Do you have SQL Server Management Studio to play with queries and test different things or is everything you do through Spreadsheet Server?  I am not familiar with that product but a lot of those things do things "for you" and it is sometimes hard to get them to do things in a specific way.